# How to do continuous course evaluation and feedback

Tags: teacher-evaluations

Typically universities ask students to evaluate each course at the end of semester. "On the scale of 1 to 5 how well did X do Y"-type questions.

I rather do a *continuous* survey, from the first day to the last. While the topics are still hot in each person's mind "what is working and what is not working"-type questionnaire.
More of an open format and less of 1 through 5 format.
I think, especially for online classes, this will help us keep things running smoother.

The question is what is a good format or software for doing such a thing.
Typically we want it to be anonymous but limited to students who are taking the class.

Is there a version of Blackboard that allows anonymous comments by students?
Have you used surveying sites for this purpose?
If you have you done such a thing, what were pros and cons, what software or site did you use?

Comment: Week 1: this course is too much work. Week 2: this course is still too much work, plus I got a bad grade on the first quiz, which is unfair. Week 3: teacher wouldn't take my late homework papers, UNFAIR! Week 4: The second quiz had a question on it that wasn't exactly like the homework, ***UNFAIR!!***

Comment: I believe Blackboard has a way to create a Discussion Board forum that allows anonymous posts. You can just create a general forum named "Feedback" with the description of "leave your anonymous feedback here" EDIT: Here, this page shows that anonymous posts are possible: https://blackboardhelp.usc.edu/collaboration/forums/creating-a-discussion-forum/

Comment: @BenCrowell, That is a physical law, with a half life greater than that of protons. Good for Chapter 0 of Light and Matter. Great book.

Answer (score 2):

## Consider a less technological solution

Students, especially in modern times, are already using a big bunch of different online platforms and their functionalities. Adding one more is not a good solution, and, in particular, since it is voluntary, it would likely not get used that much anyway.

At NTNU each course has a group of student representatives (referansegruppe), maybe four to seven of them per course (one per study program, or maybe everyone if it is a small course). They acts as the official representatives of the rest of the students and also write a short report at the end of the course. In my experience (with a large course intended for example for biologists and geologists) I got reasonable feedback from the representatives. Note that they can speak for anonymous students or the course student body as a whole, so it solves the issue of anonymity. It seems that at least some other Norwegian universities have similar arrangements, though the details and terminology vary.

But if you choose to burden the students with yet more systems or forms to fill, one option is to use the questionares offered by Microsoft, Google and no doubt several other actors; some of these are certainly free when it comes to price and your university might have sold their soul to Microsoft or Google, or just otherwise have some kind of arrangement with some firm that allows making surveys. Typically the surveys can be anonymous. If such a system is not integrated with your university website, then you can still distribute the link by the usual means. It is quite unlikely for anyone outside the course to sabotage the survey, even if it is technically possible.

I did use some such surveys and faced no problems. They were not associated with course feedback, so I can't comment on if they are fit for that in particular.